# Arduino Maps or Lists for LED board animations

Tags: c++, list, arduino, maps, fastled

im working with an arduino attached with 6 LED programmable strips and the FASTLED library. for animations i need to efficiently pass data to methods to create easy animations.

the leds are in a grid of 6 X 30, and the only way to light them is to specify the strip and the index on that strip.

i currently have this piece of code to pass the strip and leds through easily:

```
//i want to pass the data through as this: setArrayLeds(   [{1,4,5,6},{2,4,5,6}] );
//where the first index per array is the led strip, the latter the leds.

void setArrayLeds(int list[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){

       int led[] = list[i];

       for(int j = 1; j < led.length(); j++){

          //array with ledstrip individally assignable
          ArrayOfLeds[led[0]][led[j]].setRGB(255,0,0);

        }

      }
}
```

but even better option would be to use maps to pass data around, such as this code

```
setMapsLeds( map containing > 1:{1,2,3,4}, 2:{5,6,7}, 3:{8,9,10});
```

where a function will iterate over the keys and light the corresponding leds on the right ledstrip.

do you guys have any idea how to make this possible

Comment: Warning: arrays have no member functions. `int led[] = list[i];` isn't proper either.

Comment: `std::vector` of `std::pair` may be suited to that you want. There's a lot of overhead in C++'s `map` that you aren't going to be using.